# Shopify PriceRule Create Mutation

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to create a Price Rule to automatically apply a discount at checkout. I am getting the error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Parse error on \"1\" (INT) at [4, 24]",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 24
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From mutation:

```
mutation priceRuleCreate($priceRule: PriceRuleInput!) {
  priceRuleCreate(priceRule: $priceRule) {
    priceRule {
      allocationLimit: 1,
      allocationMethod: "ACROSS",
         customerSelection: {
        customerIdsToAdd: ["gid://shopify/Customer/5476062265403"]
      },
      itemEntitlements: {
        collectionIds: ["gid://shopify/Collection/267286741051"]
      },
      itemPrerequisites: {
        collectionIds: ["gid://shopify/Collection/267286741051"]
      },
      prerequisiteShippingPriceRange: {
        greaterThanOrEqualTo: 0.00
      },
      prerequisiteSubtotalRange: {
        greaterThanOrEqualTo: 0.00
    },
    prerequisiteQuantityRange: {
        greaterThan: 1
    },
    shippingEntitlements: {
      countryCodes: ["US"],
      includeRestOfWorld: true
    },
    usageLimit: 3,
    title: "HB-131",
    target: "LINE_ITEM",
    value: {
      fixedAmountValue: 10.00
    },
    validityPeriod: {
        start: "2019-09-07T15:50:00Z"
      }
  }
    
  }
}
```

I'm unsure why I am getting this error since I am following the format from the documentation: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2021-04/mutations/priceRuleCreate

For context I am using the GraphQL playground app that Shopify offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply **remove** the values.

The mutation should just simply specify the fields that you need.

```
mutation priceRuleCreate($priceRule: PriceRuleInput!) {
  priceRuleCreate(priceRule: $priceRule) {
    priceRule {
      allocationLimit
    }
  }
}
```

Please refer to this [document](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations) how to craft a GraphQL mutation request

Comment: is there any way to write the query where it adds the values directly in the query and not use a separate variables object? I have a separate mutation that allowed me to write the values in directly hence this confusion

Comment: I tried to recreate the mutation and just plugin as needed and this ended with the OP

Comment: @G.Rose, yes. simply replace `PriceInput!` with an object containing the values. Refer to this page - [Mutations and Input Types](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/) for reference.